# FCM console integration with active directory

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a requirement where I want to integrate my AD on the cloud with fcm console so that I can authenticate and assign roles to the user from my own IAM. Please confirm either it is possible if so please share some details.

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase console uses Google Cloud IAM roles to determine who has access. Based on that knowledge, you might be able to find more information, such as this page on [Federating Google Cloud with Active Directory](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/identity/federating-gcp-with-active-directory-introduction) or more of these [search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=manage+google+cloud+iam+from+active+directory).